# Set deployment target for CocoaPods's pod

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

I use CocoaPods to manage dependencies in my project. I've written Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'KeepLayout', :git => 'https://github.com/iMartinKiss/KeepLayout', :tag => 'v1.6.0'
  pod 'EasyMapping'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This file works well with CocoaPods 0.x but I can't compile project after I've updated to CocoaPods 1.0. After I've run

```
pod update
```

I can't compile my project with error:

> /Users/<...>/Pods/KeepLayout/Sources/KeepAttribute.m:195:1: Cannot synthesize weak property because the current deployment target does not support weak references

I've seen that every library is builded with different deployment target. For example KeepLayout is builded with 4.3 deployment target.

How I can determine build target for every pod dependency?

Comment: Temporary solution: go in xcode, click the 'Pods' project, and set the deployment target above 6, I think, when 'weak' appeared. I have 8.0.

But after each pod install it reverts to 4, so I'm also curios about a definitive solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've created it before, but do not think that it is a good solution.

Comment: Also I've find script to create it automatic for every target from the project, but it does  not work with CocoaPods 1.0. :(

Comment: `pod update` is setting the deployment target of the pod to iOS 4.3 because that is the default deployment target if the podspec doesn't specify one. This was an intentional decision by the CocoaPods team, even though it breaks some older pods that basically have an incomplete podspec. If you are maintaining the pod, you should specify an appropriate target, e.g. `platform :ios, '8.0'` to fix it. If you are just trying to use a pod that is broken in this way, please try my suggestion below.

Comment: @codrut thank you for the quick fix. For anyone else looking I have just updated to Cocoapods 1.0.0. This required a syntax change in my podfile. I am using maybe 15 pods which all compiled fine except for MBProgressHUD. The pods project itself is set to 8.0 as defined in my Podfile, but for some reason the MBProgressHUD target was set to 4.3. The fix listed blow by Alex Nauda works great for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

While some development versions of CocoaPods (as well as pre-1.0 versions) may have propagated the deployment target of the project down to the pods, this is [no longer the case in 1.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4636). To work around this, [the current developer recommends](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4859) using a post-install hook.

Here's a brute force approach to force a hard-coded deployment target for every pod in the generated Pods project. Paste this at the ***end*** of your `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.2'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Replace `'9.2'` with whatever deployment target you would like to use.

Comment: We've updated the library's specs, but your solution great.

Comment: What is the setting for macOS?

Comment: MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Comment: @AlexNauda is there any way to install specific pod if target's Deployment target is >= 9.0.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the key `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` from every target settings?  Project already set its deployment target, and every target just inherit it.

Comment: Where do I find the file into which this code needs to be inserted?

Answer (score 164):

Since the `Podfile` uses a directive like `platform :ios, '9.0'` to specify "iOS Deployment Target" (aka `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`) for the Pods/Pods.xcodeproj project, you just need to **remove** the **Deployment Target** info from each build target.
Do it by adding this to your `Podfile`

```rb
platform :ios, '9.0' # set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET for the pods project
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Inspired by the [github post](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1347) and Alex Nauda's answer.

Comment: @bluebamboo append it to your `Podfile`

Comment: Yes - removing the specific setting and using your default seems a tidier solution than repeating your deployment target (just another thing to go wrong).

Comment: How do I find this podfile?

Comment: I found it - the Podfile appears to be a file named "Podfile" in the project

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: how it will work ? I mean i tried with pod install but still no effect and got same error had to upgrade manually.

Answer (score 23):

Here is the way to set **deployment target permanently for pod** targets.

Goto -> podfile -> Add below code

```html
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = "12.0"
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13):

While the accepted answer by *Alex Nauda* is good, but letting the Pods inherit the target from the app might be a much better solution.

```
app_ios_deployment_target = Gem::Version.new('9.2') # Change to your current deployment target

platform :ios, app_ios_deployment_target.version

# Let Pods targets inherit deployment target from the app
# This solution is suggested here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4859
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      pod_ios_deployment_target = Gem::Version.new(configuration.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
      if pod_ios_deployment_target <= app_ios_deployment_target
        configuration.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5
Simple Solution Copy paste the below code into the end of your podFile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.1' #set your minimum version your all pods will set to mininum 13.1 version :-)
    end
  end
end
```

install your pods

```
//MARK: - Run the command in your terminal
pod install
```

Happy Coding

Comment: The comment starting with // caused issues for me.  Replace with #.

Comment: oh Great JOEL in pod file comment start with # I just changed you can check thanks for others help

Answer (score -1):

change target to "11.0"

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

1) Search for IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

2) Change the iOS Deployment Target

[image]

Comment: This is not a long-term solution.  A "pod install" will revert the setting back to whatever was in the podspec.

Comment: @JohnFowler what is the long-term solution?

Comment: @OpeyemiNoah Long-term solution is to update the podfile in one of the manners listed in the acceptable solutions above. By updating the podfile, running a "pod install" will set the deployment target to the desired value.