# FBSDKLoginKit - UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I am using FBSDKLoginKit to provide facebook login in my swift project. My deployment target is 9.0 but I keep on getting the following warnings. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

- UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer
- UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer
- openURL:options:completionHandler:' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

In my **AppDelegate.swift** I have the following for Facebook login:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: Iam using Cocoapods and this solved it for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289688/956701