# -[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

Using Firebase Analytics in an ios app, on a phone and simulator using ios 15.4, XCode 13.2.1 (13C100) in a React Native app.
The app itself works, but when I try to add unit tests, the test runner fails with the unrecognized selector problem. I have combed the issues on SO, they either ask for more info and die on the vine, or reference the same four issues on Firebase's github.

The Podfile (below) doesn't have use_frameworks! so it's unlikely that duplicate symbols are the culprit. I tried the one concrete piece of advice from the github issues, `pod deintegrate` and recreate Podfile.lock, to no avail.

Here is the crash log, and below is the Podfile:

```
2022-02-01 17:59:06.733484-0800 ******[15233:34721677] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003d17db0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011356eba4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dee1be7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011357d811 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001135730ac ___forwarding___ + 1433
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001135751d8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ******                            0x00000001004111a0 -[GDTCCTUploadOperation updateNextUploadTimeWithResponse:forTarget:] + 96
    6   ******                            0x00000001004105ca __64-[GDTCCTUploadOperation sendURLRequestWithBatch:target:storage:]_block_invoke + 74
    7   ******                            0x000000010044ad65 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.67 + 85
    8   ******                            0x000000010044a62a __44-[FBLPromise observeOnQueue:fulfill:reject:]_block_invoke_2 + 106
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011147965a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011147a83a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111480f2d _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1032
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001114819d0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011148c57d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 772
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114c1745d _pthread_wqthread + 314
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114c1642f start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/rmd6502/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-ezrzirhsblfqhfcbpxivqdehqlic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/rmd6502/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-ezrzirhsblfqhfcbpxivqdehqlic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/******.app/Frameworks/libXCTestBundleInject.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/rmd6502/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/******-ezrzirhsblfqhfcbpxivqdehqlic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003d17db0'
```

Podfile:

````
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '14.0'

target '******' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'RNInputMask', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-text-input-mask/ios/InputMask'
  pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '4f3c694920ed0f5d3a8e180aacaf3af40c2efb4a'
  pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '3.14.1'
  pod 'EDQueue', :git => 'https://github.com/*****/queue.git', :commit => '06307feabc8893dee182732ed9f7662dcee2c4e8'
  pod 'FMDB/standalone'
  pod 'OpenCV2', '4.0.1'
  pod 'TrueTime'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/ABTesting'

  # pod 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'

  
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # based on https://github.com/facebook/flipper/commit/42325e41c5b7a7173281e57cdc3bfb9aee76340d
  # TODO: add a RELEASE mode exemption too, or replace the CI check with it
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.4.3', 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' => '3.1.7', 'Flipper-Glog' => '0.3.9', 'Flipper-PeerTalk' => '0.0.4' })
  #   post_install do |installer|
  #     flipper_post_install(installer)
  #     # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289688/1983583
  #     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  #       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  #         config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
  #       end
  #     end
  #   end
  # end

  target '*****Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end```
````

Comment: Oh I fixed "FirebaseAnalytics" -> "Firebase/Analytics" in case of version mismatch, didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue was `inherit! :complete` for the test target was duplicating the Promise library and causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

`Firebase/MLVision` has been deprecated for a few years, so there may be some incompatible versions mixed into the app.

Best bet is to update to GoogleMLKit. If not that, you may be able to find compatible old versions by exploring the information in the generated `Podfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

While this is another bug caused by using Firebase, I was able to resolve the issue and it was just a condition in XCTest that creates a crash.

- Followed the guidance in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup?authuser=0&hl=en#swift_1) by adding `-ObjC` to the Other Linker Flags (found in Build Settings)
- Removed the empty `testPerformance` method for new XCTest Classes.

The second step was revealed when I added any new XCTest class and the  crash was always present.  Removing it allowed the tests to run