# Xcode Build Failed due to Firebase AppAuth bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a build for iOS which include Firebase auth for Google Login. It works fine in Android build but when I am trying for iOS it produces following error in Xcode:

> '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gbwpuctwjyrotehhhhpzgerqcggr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises(FBLPromise.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gbwpuctwjyrotehhhhpzgerqcggr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' for architecture arm64

I have searched for solution that suggest to enable bitcode to set NO in Xcode build setting but it does not work.

I am using following versions:
Unity version : 21.3.21
Firebase version : 11.3.0
Xcode version : 14.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBLPromises.framework does not contain bitcode - failing build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904371/fblpromises-framework-does-not-contain-bitcode-failing-build)

Comment: I had to set Bitcode to 'No' as docs, but still it's not working, is there any other solution for same