# troubles with bitcode when building an app with fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I am trying to setup a pipeline in github to create an application with fastlane and push it to the appstore.

I have some troubles understanding bitcode problematics, more over with the different versions of xcode. My trouble happen when I try to build the app, because one of my dependancy does not have bitcode in it. here is the stacktrace about the error:

```
ld: '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-hktscdrwwpxombeaagjploucipfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAEvent.o)'
does not contain bitcode.You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.
file '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-hktscdrwwpxombeaagjploucipfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics'
for architecture arm64
```

and here is my build_app action (I skipped the match part and all)

```
build_app(
      workspace: use_workspace ? ENV['WORKSPACE_PATH'] : nil,
      project: !use_workspace ? ENV['PROJECT_PATH'] : nil,
      scheme: "App",
      output_directory: File.dirname(ENV['OUTPUT_PATH']),
      output_name: File.basename(ENV['OUTPUT_PATH']),
      clean: true,
      export_method: ENV['EXPORT_METHOD'],
      export_team_id: ENV['TEAM_ID'],
      silent: true
    )
```

and the current versions I am using:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------+
|               Build environment                |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app |
| gym_version   | 2.214.0                        |
| export_method | app-store                      |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS15.2.sdk               |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

however, I understand that bitcode is deprecated, so it should not be a problem to not have bitcode ? Or if one part of the app have bit code have bitcode, all should?

Just in case, I also added the following key in the info.plist:

```
    <key>ENABLE_BITCODE</key>
    <false/>
```

but without much success. I am pretty sure, it would be an easy problematic to setup in xcode on a local machine ([like this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904371/fblpromises-framework-does-not-contain-bitcode-failing-build)), but I am a windows user, and therefor cannot run it.

I believe I am missing something obvious, but cannot figure it out... help would be much appreciated!

cheers,

Comment: Either everything must have bitcode or everything must not have bitcode. You can't mix and match. As you say, bitcode is deprecated, so turn it off everywhere.

Comment: that is what I thought too. Have an idea on how to do so in fastlane ?